# Checking if radio button group has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a form with an array of radio button options.

```
<input type="radio" name="prof['.NET']" value="Advanced" class="prof">
<input type="radio" name="prof['.NET']" value="Intermediate" class="prof">
<input type="radio" name="prof['.NET']" value="Beginner" class="prof">
<input type="radio" name="prof['.NET']" value="None" class="prof">

<input type="radio" name="prof['VBA']" value="Advanced" class="prof">
<input type="radio" name="prof['VBA']" value="Intermediate" class="prof">
<input type="radio" name="prof['VBA']" value="Beginner" class="prof">
<input type="radio" name="prof['VBA']" value="None" class="prof">
```

I am trying to loop through each group of radio buttons and see if one has been selected from each group.

I am just not familiar with how to loop through arrays like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking if button from group is selected, You can use:

```
$('input:radio[name="prof[\'.NET\']"]').is(":checked");
```

and

```
$('input:radio[name="prof[\'VBA\']"]').is(":checked");
```

Comment: Can this be done dynamically though ? The options will never be the same

Comment: Yes you can. that depends whether we get the selector for them.

Comment: The only things that will change is this var `prof['.NET']` it could be anything

Comment: @SBB You need some have some unique identifier for how you want to query these groups of radio inputs. Wrap them in a div with a class then, if there is no uniformity in the name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a completely generic solution.  Ia dded a check button and set the following click event:

```
$('#check').click(function(){
    var names = {};
    $('.prof').filter(':radio').each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        if( undefined === names[name] ){
            names[name] = false;
        }
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            names[name] = true;
        }
    });

    $.each(names, function(name, val){
        if( !val ){
            alert(name + ' is not selected');
        }
    });
});
```

If, however, you wish to valiate that it has been selected you might want to check out the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation) instead (there may well be others, that's the one I use).  Then you just add a required class.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/ctr91n2a/)